# How can i cast from Func<Object> to Func<dynamicType> c#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Hello this is my first post, don't be to hard if I do anything wrong :D

I am writing a DeSerializer for a big Programm,
To do so, I have a own Class

```
public class DeSerializeableElement
{
    public Func<Object> action;
    public Type type;

    public DeSerializeableElement( Func<Object> p_action,Type p_type)
    {   
        type = p_type;
        action = p_action;
    }
```

I read a String and then it always starts with 0XXX a 4 digit number.
with this number I get the right method from my

```
Dictionary<int,DeSerializableElement>
```

the initialize of the Dictionary is auto Generated and has 300 elements

```
deSerializableObjectDictionary.Add(276, new DeSerializeableElement(GetString, typeof(System.String)));
```

GetString is a method with no parameters and returns a String

Now my problem, if I Deserialize a List, at the moment I create a DeSerializableElement the Func looses its return value Information. Because I save it as Func so I get back a List 
but it`s Important to get a List in case of GetString
there are also GetInt or GetDouble and lots more

So If i call GetList(GetString) I want as return value a List
and if I call GetList(GetInt) I want a List and so on.
But I get always a List because my SerializableElement has Func as attribute

The call for GetList looks like

```
GetList(deSerializableObjectDictionary[objectIdent].action);
```

GetList looks like

```
public IList<T> GetList<T>(Func<T> p_action) //T is always Object because of Func<Object> here I the right Type
{
    IList<T> list = new List<T>();
    ExpectToken('[');          //The start Token of a serialized List
    while (!IsNextToken(']'))  //End Token of serialized List
    {
        list.Add(p_action());
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you make it more explicit what isn't working and what you want to do?

Comment: So you want to return a `List<int>` for `int`, and `List<string>` for `string`?

Comment: Yes thats what I want

Comment: Pretty doubtful that's what you want, throwing type-safety away is almost never not a mistake, but you can't discover this until you try.  You'll have to use Delegate or `Func<dynamic>`.

Comment: Whichever way you look at it, you'll need some sort of run-time casting to make this work. Use that with caution.

Comment: If I use Func<dynamic> I it`s like Func<object> and i get Lis<Object> back and i can`t make a dictionairy of generic type

Comment: If I call getList, I know which type I want, can`t i make something like Type t and List<t>? Or can I make a Dictionary of generic types?

Answer (score 0):

Any road you choose, it will one such that you are losing type safety. For example, you can defer to a `Dictionary<int, object>` and wrap that with a `GetList<T>` method where `T` is the actual type you want. A mis-use of this method can lead to runtime exceptions.

An example would be:

```
void Main()
{
    var idToFunc = new Dictionary<int, object>();
    idToFunc.Add(1, new DeSerializeableElement<int>(() => 1));

    Console.WriteLine(GetList<int>(((DeSerializeableElement<int>) idToFunc[1]).Func));
}

public class DeSerializeableElement<T>
{
    public Func<T> Func { get; set; }
    public DeSerializeableElement(Func<T> func)
    {
        Func = func;
    }
}
```

I would definitely of the risks involved with this kind of code. Although possible, I would advise you to re-think what you're doing and the architecture of your deserializer.